# Capturing incorrect format of a text pattern with Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I have empty folders that have `NA -` at the beginning of them. The correct format of these should be

> "NA - FolderName"

Unfortunately not all people have followed this naming convention. I am trying to write a Regex to capture all patterns of the NA - that is **incorrectly formated or repeating the NA -**.

Regex I've come up with so far is

> N ?A ?-((?![0-9.A-MO-Z][B-Z]| )|.?N ?A ?-)

Here are the folder names I've used to test it. The ones with ***Incorrect*** in the name have *NA -* not in the correct format and the ones I want to capture the *NA -* format in:

```
NA -IncorrectFolderName1
N A-1. IncorrectFolderName2
N A- 1. IncorrectFolderName3
NA-IncorrectFolderName4
N A -1.IncorrectFolderName5
NA -NA -IncorrectFolderName6
NA - NA -IncorrectFolderName7
N A - N A - IncorrectFolderName8
N A - NA - IncorrectFolderName9

NA - CorrectFolderName1
NA - 1CorrectFolderName2
NA - 1. CorrectFolderName3
```

SEE CODE HERE FOR EXAMPLE OF WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO: https://regex101.com/r/9Bzo43/6

The only incorrect format left that my code won't capture is:

```
N A- 1. IncorrectFolderName3
```

The Regex should not capture the correctly formatted "NA - " folders like the ones below. These codes should not be captured.

```
RegularFolderName1
NA - CorrectFolderName1
NA - 1CorrectFolderName2
NA - 1. CorrectFolderName3
```

I have been researching Regex and I am close but I can't seem to figure out how to write it to find all the desired patterns of the incorrect code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `-replace '^(?:N\s*A\b\P{L}*)+'`, see https://regex101.com/r/EksTdw/2

Comment: Or, `^N\s*A(?:\s*(?:-\s*)?N\s*A)*(?:\s*-\s*(?:\d+\.)?)*\s*`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/EksTdw/3). It would be helpful if you could precise the *etcetera* part of the requirements.

Comment: are you going to rename the items with your desired pattern? if so, then you may simply want to grab all files that start with `N`, are followed by one or more of `A` or ` `, and then a hyphen. once you have that list, split on the hyphen, take the last item, and add your proper prefix.

Comment: `-notmatch "^NA - (?!NA -)"` - https://regex101.com/r/9Bzo43/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, maybe

```
(?:(?:N\s*A\s*)-\s*){2}|N\s+A\s*-\s*(?=\d+\.\s*)|NA-|NA\s+-(?=\S)
```

or some similar expressions with alternation would be much simple to write and debug.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pgxkuy/1)

I wasn't sure what we would and wouldn't like to capture at endings, any ending part you wouldn't want to swipe/capture you can simply place it in a positive lookahead `(?=)`, which is a zero-width assertion, such as:

```
NA\s+-(?=\S)
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Pgxkuy/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Pgxkuy/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I was wrecking my brain on this one. Thank you for the additional insights as well.

Comment: Sorry about this, just noticed that it still captures numbers in those with numbers after the pattern. Those like `N A-1. IncorrectFolderName2, N A- 1. IncorrectFolderName3, N A -1.IncorrectFolderName5`. Anyway around this?

Comment: Thank you again. Works as intended. I have a lot to learn about Lookaround Assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Using your examples, this works:

```
$foldernames =  'NA -IncorrectFolderName1',
                'N A-1. IncorrectFolderName2',
                'N A- 1. IncorrectFolderName3',
                'NA-IncorrectFolderName4',
                'N A -1.IncorrectFolderName5',
                'NA -NA -IncorrectFolderName6',
                'NA - NA -IncorrectFolderName7',
                'N A - N A - IncorrectFolderName8',
                'N A - NA - IncorrectFolderName9',
                'RegularFolderName1',
                'NA - CorrectFolderName1',
                'NA - 1CorrectFolderName2',
                'NA - 1. CorrectFolderName3'

$newNames = $foldernames | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^(?:(N\s*A\s*-\s*))+(.+)', 'NA - $2' }

$newNames
```

Result:

> ```
> NA - IncorrectFolderName1
> NA - 1. IncorrectFolderName2
> NA - 1. IncorrectFolderName3
> NA - IncorrectFolderName4
> NA - 1.IncorrectFolderName5
> NA - IncorrectFolderName6
> NA - IncorrectFolderName7
> NA - IncorrectFolderName8
> NA - IncorrectFolderName9
> RegularFolderName1
> NA - CorrectFolderName1
> NA - 1CorrectFolderName2
> NA - 1. CorrectFolderName3
> ```

Regex details:

```
(?:              Match the regular expression below
   (             Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
      N          Match the character “N” literally
      \s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
         *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      A          Match the character “A” literally
      \s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
         *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      -          Match the character “-” literally
      \s         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
         *       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   )
)+               Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   .             Match any single character that is not a line break character
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```